# How to share a camera view between two devices via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I want two devices to be connected via bluetooth. Device A should be using a camera and Device B is able to see what Device A is viewing via the camera. Device B should also be able to take videos and pictures via Device A's camera. Any idea on how I could implement this? I have already set up the bluetooth connections using Android's code:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

It should look something like this but between two phones : https://www.youtube.com/watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you some ideas,

1. Device A should listen for commands via bluetooth
2. Device B should listen for incoming frames via bluetooth
3. in Device A camera onPreviewFrame, capture the frame and send it to a dedicated thread which will process it and send it (byte array) to Device B via bluetooth.
4. Device B should get the Byte array decode to bitmap and display it on a surfaceview, imageview or anything else that is able to show an Image
5. on bluetooth message receive Device A should control its camera to take picture and perform other actions.

Comment: how would you send a frame as a byte array?

Comment: camera onPreviewFrame callback directly gives you a byte array.

Comment: ok, and how will device A continuously send Device B a stream of frames?

Comment: there will be a handler thread. as soon as onPreviewFrame is called it should pack the byte array in handler message object and send it to handler thread. the handler thread will send the byte array via bluetooth. you can skip frames to optimize things. like send every 2nd frame.

Comment: how would i skip the frames?

Comment: well keep a counter. in onPreviewFrame do counter++. if counter % n ==0 then it means its the nth frame. you will send that frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114464/discussion-between-nilay-neeranjun-and-dumb-terminal).